# nginx: auth_basic and php

Tags: php, authentication, nginx

i want to protect a folder of my website with a password using auth_basic. This folder contains php-scripts which should be executed if they are requested.

I tried the following:

```
location /admin {
  auth_basic    "Admin-Section";
  auth_basic_user_file /myfolder/.htpasswd;
 }

 location ~ ^/admin/.*\.php$ {
  auth_basic    "Admin-Section";
  auth_basic_user_file /myfolder/.htpasswd;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include   fastcgi_params;
 }
```

I will be asked for username/password when requesting the php-scripts in that admin-folder, but the php-scripts will always be downloaded instead of executed via fastcgi.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: On my local machine everything works fine with this configuration. o0
EDIT: BTW, php is working outside the admin-folder with the same fastcgi-options.
EDIT: OMG! The site's config was stored at /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ contained a symlink to the mysite-file. Since some time changing the mysite-file had no effect. E.g. changing all locations to "deny all" had no effect. The files were sent without a problem.
So i removed the symlink and restarted the server. Then i created the symlink again, restarted the server and everything works as expected. Can someone explain the odd behaviour?

Gest regards,
Biggie

Answer (score 16):

With this configuration, nginx will only match **one** of the two blocks - the one with the highest precedence.

The solution is to combine the PHP block *into* the AUTH block.  This is the approach recommended by the nginx author himself, Igor Sysoev.

```
location /admin/ {
  auth_basic    "Admin-Section";
  auth_basic_user_file /myfolder/.htpasswd;
  location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include       fastcgi_params;
  }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include       fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid the obvious code duplication?

Comment: Put the duplicated code in a separate file and include it from each block.

Comment: I understand that this is how nginx works, but this has bitten me so many times that it's not funny anymore. I literally need to re-include everything in every location block where I want to change some behavior. This is really painful, even when using a large amount of snippet files. One little mistake and some `auth_basic` or `deny` directives might fail to apply in unexpected ways (since regex matches may take precedence over prefix matches). Very error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just had the same problem, so here's the explanation.

Nginx uses [the rules described in the docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) to match the location blocks. For conventional blocks, the longest match will be the one that will be applied, but for regular expressions it's **always the first matching** block that will be applied.

In your production server, you most likely had a `location ~ \.php$` block above your admin block, hence the listen block you posted was never applied.

Long short story: when dealing with regular expression listen blocks in nginx, order matters. Put the more specific matches before the general ones.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the following line:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: That's a necessary line when php-fpm is running in a chroot jail.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you forgot to add root:

```
location ~ .\php$ {
    #Lines of code...
    root /your/document/root;
    #Lines of code...
}

location /admin/ {
    #Lines of code...
    root /your/document/root;
    #Lines of code...
}
```